# Show ContextMenu for TreeViewItem by raising events in code

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, coded-ui-tests

I want to write a coded UI test for my treeview with context menu. The idea is to validate if the context menu is added to treeViewItem.

So far I tried to raise `PreviewMouseRightButtonUp` event. This is not working.

If I subscribe to the event then I get a callback after right-clicking the tree item. But raising the event manual does not cause the context menu to be added.

Here is how I am raising the event:

```
MouseButtonEventArgs eventArgs = new MouseButtonEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, 0, MouseButton.Right);
eventArgs.RoutedEvent = Mouse.MouseUpEvent;
uiElement.RaiseEvent(eventArgs);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate if the context menu is added to treeViewItem, why not right-click on the tree item and look for the existence of a menu in the window.

Comment: Thanks for replying. My intention is to write a coded UI test. I do not wish to manually execute the test case. That defeats the whole purpose.

Comment: What i have said above is to write it through coded-ui, not do it manually.